# Закрытие фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

По нажатию на элемент списка я изменяю язык, помимо этого я пытаюсь закрывать фрагмент в котором расположен данный список с помощью следующего отрывка кода:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

Но так как при выборе элемента из списка(меняю язык для приложения) я также сохраняю данный выбор в SharedPreference. И возможно поэтому у меня крэшится приложение.

Вот собственно и ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                    at com.vm.sai.features.settings.LanguagesSelectorFragment.saveLocale(LanguagesSelectorFragment.java:69)
>                                                                    at com.vm.sai.features.settings.LanguagesSelectorFragment.changeLang(LanguagesSelectorFragment.java:60)
>                                                                    at com.vm.sai.features.settings.LanguagesSelectorFragment.lambda$-com_vm_sai_features_settings_LanguagesSelectorFragment_lambda$1(LanguagesSelectorFragment.java:103)
>                                                                    at com.vm.sai.features.settings.-$Lambda$17.$m$0(Unknown Source)
>                                                                    at com.vm.sai.features.settings.-$Lambda$17.onRVItemClick(Unknown Source)
>                                                                    at com.vm.sai.adapters.LanguagesAdapter.lambda$-com_vm_sai_adapters_LanguagesAdapter_lambda$1(LanguagesAdapter.java:51)
>                                                                    at com.vm.sai.adapters.-$Lambda$21.$m$0(Unknown Source)
>                                                                    at com.vm.sai.adapters.-$Lambda$21.onClick(Unknown Source)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Так раз падает в строках где я сохраняю свои локали:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Пробовал комментировать метод, в котором сохраняю язык в sp. Но всё же выбивает ошибку уже в другом месте:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getBaseContext()' on a null object reference
>                                                                      at com.vm.sai.features.settings.LanguagesSelectorFragment.changeLang(LanguagesSelectorFragment.java:64)
>                                                                      at com.vm.sai.features.settings.LanguagesSelectorFragment.lambda$-com_vm_sai_features_settings_LanguagesSelectorFragment_lambda$1(LanguagesSelectorFragment.java:103)
>                                                                      at com.vm.sai.features.settings.-$Lambda$17.$m$0(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.vm.sai.features.settings.-$Lambda$17.onRVItemClick(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.vm.sai.adapters.LanguagesAdapter.lambda$-com_vm_sai_adapters_LanguagesAdapter_lambda$1(LanguagesAdapter.java:51)
>                                                                      at com.vm.sai.adapters.-$Lambda$21.$m$0(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.vm.sai.adapters.-$Lambda$21.onClick(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

В строчке:

```
getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Вот целиком код фрагмента:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_languages, container, false);
    initViews(view);
    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();
    loadLocale();
    return view;
}

protected void initViews(View view) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), null));
}

public void loadLocale() {
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString(langPref, "");
    changeLang(language);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void changeLang(String lang) {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    saveLocale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

public void saveLocale(String lang) {
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(langPref, lang);
    editor.apply();
}

private void initializeData() {
    languages = new ArrayList<>();
    languages.add(new Languages(getString(R.string.english)));
    languages.add(new Languages(getString(R.string.russian)));
    languages.add(new Languages(getString(R.string.deutsch)));
    languages.add(new Languages(getString(R.string.romana)));
}

private void initializeAdapter() {
    LanguagesAdapter languagesAdapter = new LanguagesAdapter(languages, position -> {
        String lang = "en";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                lang = "en";
                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                break;
            case 1:
                lang = "ru";
                break;
            case 2:
                lang = "de";
                break;
            case 3:
                lang = "ro";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        changeLang(lang);
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(languagesAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (myLocale != null) {
        newConfig.locale = myLocale;
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Comment: наверное вы в префы писать пытаетесь после закрытия фрагмента, а надо до

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не совсем понятно как записать в префы до, ведь у меня это всё во фрагменте происходит, а закрытия данного фрагмента в активити. Обновил код, возможно будет более понятней в чём проблема.

Comment: Из кода не видно когда методы с ошибками вызываются. С префами можно временно решить проблему путём получения контекста из синглтона класса Applicaton. А вот локаль во фрагменте менять - странна идея. Меняйте локаль в активити - фрагмент подъватит её из актиивити. Так вам последний метод будет не нужен и там не будет падатьэ

Comment: Не знаю тогда как ещё показать. Почему странная? Ну то есть какая разница где реализовывать во фрагменте или в активити?

Comment: Вообще большая. Хз что с фрагментом будет в процессе смены конфигурации. У вас вот он в активити вообще не добавлен, потому и падает